# how to get data from "link in click" and how to get specific type without passing on the whole site

Tags: bash, wget

I using **wget** to get some data from site that looks like this :

[image]
I have 2 question that i didn't find answers for them.
 the question is orthogonal but i how there is a solution which solves both of them

First of all, when i use that function in some version :
`wget -r -nd -k`
`wget -r -nd -k -A .xml`
**etc..**

**First of al*l* the function pass over the whole site and it take alot of time, my question is if there is combination of flags or another version of the function that not pass on the whole site?

**Secondly**, when i use the function i get only the the data on the current site, but i look for the data in the "link click" on the current site and not for the data on the site, Picture below:

[image]

I know that the big problem here is my weakness in web area, but i hope there is an easy solution that could help me the bridge on the weakness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `--accept-regex` option, which [can filter complete URLs](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options).

```
wget -r --accept-regex .xml http://example.com/page
```

This way, WGET will download: the page you specified and the XML files linked on that page, and nothing more.

(But if your XML files are linked from a subpage you want to reach with the recursive mode, URL filtering may not help, since WGET needs to download the page which directly links the XML files, to reach them.)

If you don't need the specified page, you can add `-A xml` too. That way, WGET will delete anything other than XML files at the end.

```
wget -r --accept-regex .xml -A xml http://example.com/page
```

I hope this helps.